# TensorFlow - Unable to get Prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, kaggle

I am trying to solve the [Titanic Problem on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic) and I am unsure of how to get the output for a given test data.

I successfully train the network and call the method `make_prediction(x, test_x)`

```
x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, ip_features])
...
def make_prediction(x, test_data):
  with tf.Session() as sess :
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    prediction = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: test_data})
    return prediction
```

I am not sure how to pass a `np.array` in this case `test_data` to get back a `np.array` which contains the prediction `0/1`

[Link to Full Code](https://github.com/DollarAkshay/Python-Programs/blob/f46b017ca0de88f54419b76c84a3f8ddfd324dfc/Kaggle/Titanic/Titanic.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combined your `train_neural_network` and `make_prediction` function into one single function. Applying `tf.nn.softmax` to the model function would make the value range into from 0~1 (interpreted as probability), then `tf.argmax` extracts the column number with the higher probability. Note that the `placeholder` for `y` in this case needs to be one-hot-encoded. (If you are not one-hot-encoding y here, then `pred_y=tf.round(tf.nn.softmax(model))` would convert the output of `softmax` into 0 or 1)

```
def train_neural_network_and_make_prediction(train_X, test_X):

    model = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(model, y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
    pred_y=tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(model),1)

    ephocs = 10

    with tf.Session() as sess :
        tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
        for epoch in range(ephocs):
            epoch_cost = 0

            i = 0
            while i< len(titanic_train) :
                start = i
                end = i+batch_size
                batch_x = np.array( train_x[start:end] )
                batch_y = np.array( train_y[start:end] )

                _, c = sess.run( [optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y} )
                epoch_cost += c
                i+=batch_size
            print("Epoch",epoch+1,"completed with a cost of", epoch_cost)
        # make predictions on test data
        predictions = pred_y.eval(feed_dict={x : test_X})
    return predictions
```

Comment: Thank you so much `pred_y=tf.round(tf.nn.softmax(model))` is what I was looking for :)